# convert string fetched with php nl2dr into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am pulling a data from `MySql` table which is a `textarea value`. I want to trigger the `new lines` so I have used php `nl2dr()` function for it. If I use this function then the data is being populated in new lines where user has pressed the `Enter` key while submitting the form. But I want to push each new line in an `array`.

> Sql

```
$sql = "SELECT desc FROM mytable WHERE username = '$uname'";
$res = $con->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows > 0)
{
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $desc = nl2dr($res['desc']);
    echo $desc;
}
```

If I do like this then the data is display like below...

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
.....
.....
line8
```

But I want to `push` all the lines in an `array`. So I have inspect with firefox debugger and saw that a `<br>` is there at the end of each line. So I tried this to convert it into an array.

```
$arr = explode('<br>', $desc);
var_dump($arr);
```

But it does not work. It takes the whole data as a single array.

Comment: it's `nl2br` not `nl2dr`?  can you show what is there in `$desc` by printing it out?

Comment: ..and `nl2br()` inserts `<br>` before every newline, so of course you have a `<br>` at the end of each line.

Comment: @Anant nl2br in your code is redundant

Comment: sry it's `nl2br()` . I have wrote wrong in this post. But in my original code it's nl2br()